# SQL - one-to-many and get all users that don't have

Tags: sql, join

I have users and permissions tables. Relation between them is:

One user `HAS MANY` permissions.

I need to get all users who does not have permission `hide`.

For example, users table has:

```
 id ¦ name   ¦ email           ¦ password  
 ---+ -------+-----------------+---------- 
  1 ¦ Test 1 ¦ test@gmail.com  ¦ 1234      
  2 ¦ Test 2 ¦ test2@gmail.com ¦ 2345      
  3 ¦ Test 3 ¦ test3@gmail.com ¦ 2345  
  4 ¦ Test 4 ¦ test4@gmail.com ¦ 8888
  5 ¦ Test 5 ¦ test5@gmail.com ¦ 9876
```

---

and permissions table looks like:

```
   user_id ¦ permission  
  ---------+------------ 
   1       ¦ read        
   2       ¦ edit        
   2       ¦ hide     
   4       ¦ edit   
   5       ¦ hide
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
  LEFT JOIN permissions 
         ON users.id = permissions.user_id 
        AND permissions.permission != 'hide'
```

but this still gets me second user because second user has also permission edit.

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
 id ¦ name   ¦ email           ¦ password  ¦ permission 
 ---+ -------+-----------------+---------- +------------
  1 ¦ Test 1 ¦ test@gmail.com  ¦ 1234      ¦ read      
  3 ¦ Test 3 ¦ test3@gmail.com ¦ 2345      ¦ null      
  4 ¦ Test 4 ¦ test4@gmail.com ¦ 8888      ¦ edit
```

What is best approach here?

Comment: The sample data for users table has no id column, but the query uses that column...

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data, and also specify the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Good case for `not exists`

```
SELECT * 
FROM users u
left JOIN permissions p
  ON u.id = p.user_id 
where not exists ( select 1 
                   from permissions p2
                   where p2.user_id = u.id 
                   and p2.permission = 'hide'
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM users u
left JOIN permissions p
  ON u.id = p.id 
where u.id not in 
( 
  select id
  from permissions
  where permission = 'hide'
  group by id
)
```

output

```
id  Name    Email   Password        id       permission
1   Test 1  test@gmail.com  1234    1        read
3   Test 3  test3@gmail.com 2345    (null)   (null)
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation. Code only answers should be avoided.

Comment: Nop, this doesn't give output you provided, I still see all users, but for user with permission `hide` I see permission `null`.

Comment: then just filter using `WHERE permission IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

one Possible answer  might be

```
select * from Users U
inner join Permissions P on P.id=U.id 
WHere U.id NOT IN (SELECT U.ID FROM  Users U
inner join Permissions P on P.id=U.id 
WHere P.Permission ='HIDE')
```

1) This will return ids that have hide permissions

```
SELECT U.ID FROM  Users U
inner join Permissions P on P.id=U.id 
WHere P.Permission ='HIDE'
```

2)This will return all data except the above returned ids, which will be your expected

```
select * from Users U
inner join Permissions P on P.id=U.id 
WHere  U.id NOT IN (SELECT U.ID FROM  Users U
inner join Permissions P on P.id=U.id 
WHere P.Permission ='HIDE')
```

Comment: This, similarly to solutions in previous comments will only return users that have some permission, but I also need users that don't have any permission.